# equivalent of like in mongodb spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

I would like to find the equivalent of LIKE in mongodb spring

Here is the request with the exact match

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field).is("myfield"))
```

I would like something like:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(field).LIKE("myfield"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making it regex, this results in the same ouput like in the case of `LIKE`.

```
Criteria.where(field).regex("myfield", "i");
```

Note that `i` stands for case-insensitive.